# QGIS, Table Manager cannot rename column title

Tags: qgis, table

My current attribute table has a column whose title exceeds the ten letters maximum.

I installed Table Manager, hoping I could rename the certain field to further use it (in order to add some symbology based on the values it contains). 
However, the Table Manager doesn't even show it.

Anyone knows where the problem lies?

Comment: What type of file are you trying to edit? Shapefile?

Comment: Yes. 
And just in case it might be of any importance, I added the mentioned column by joining the shapefile attribute table with an ordinary xls table.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the column is the result of a join (as mentioned in your comment above) you'll have to save the shapefile to a new file (right-click in layer legend and Save As), then add it back to the map before you can rename the column. The other option would be to change the field name in the file *before* you do the join.

Comment: I see. So far I have only worked with ArcGIS and quite some things seem to be done a bit differently with QGIS. 
Is it a general rule that every change needs to be saved as a new shapefile in order to further work with it? I remember having the same trouble changing the layer projection.

Comment: Thakns a lot thats helped me ;)

Answer (score 1):

ogr2ogr might be able to rename overlong field names, see for example the solution presented in http://darrencope.com/2011/04/26/renaming-fields-in-a-shapefile/:

```
ogr2ogr outdataset indataset -sql "SELECT src_field1 AS dst_field1, src_field2 AS dst_field2 FROM sourcelayer"
```

...but you'll have to select every column explicitly in order for it to appear in the output.

Another solution would be to rename the field in the xls document and join again with the "clean" shapefile you had before joining in the first place - only possible if you have a backup (always good, often neglected).

Comment: Thanks! It's great to see how quickly you get advice around here!